FastAPI - At POST endpoint, how to use `Depends` AFTER using Pydantic model to validate json in request body
Motivation
Use Pydantic to conveniently validate the json data in the request body, and then pass the validated Model instance object to the context class to construct the context of this request. The context class retains the original version of the parameter and prohibits modification (raw_params implemented by @property); at the same time, it provides a modifiable current parameter (curr_params) for easy context passing.
Current status
I can manually construct an instance of the context class in the request processing function, but this becomes a de facto boilerplate code (if I want to keep this behavior consistent in my project), which goes against the FastAPI philosophy of reducing code duplication.
Expectation
Automatically construct an instance of the context class through the Depends mechanism officially provided by FastAPI.
My minimal implementation
Please pay attention that this example is simplified to hide privacy-related business details.
import copy
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from uuid import uuid4

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class User(BaseModel):
    full_name: str
    nickname: str
    age: int


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: float
    alias: str = ""
    brand: str = ""


T = TypeVar("T")


class QueryContext(Generic[T]):
    """to simplify context passing"""

    def __init__(self, raw_params: T):
        self.request_UUID = uuid4()
        self._raw_params = raw_params
        self.curr_params = copy.deepcopy(raw_params)
        self.extra = {}
        return

    @property
    def raw_params(self):
        return self._raw_params

    @raw_params.setter
    def raw_params(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise AttributeError("Cannot modify raw params! Use `curr_params` instead.")


@app.post("/update_user")
async def update_user(user: User):
    ctx = QueryContext(user)  # Bad smell
    ctx.curr_params.full_name = "new full name"
    ctx.curr_params.age += 5
    print(
        f"request {ctx.request_UUID} done. raw user: {ctx.raw_params} curr params: {ctx.curr_params}"
    )
    return ctx.curr_params


@app.post("/update_item")
async def update_user(item: Item):
    ctx = QueryContext(item)  # Bad smell
    ctx.curr_params.name = "[HOT] " + ctx.curr_params.name
    ctx.curr_params.price = -1
    ctx.extra["msg"] = "Has sold out!"
    print(
        f"request {ctx.request_UUID} done. raw item: {ctx.raw_params} curr params: {ctx.curr_params} extra info: {ctx.extra}"
    )
    return ctx.curr_params

Any help is appreciated! Many thanks!

Here is solution for your problem:
def get_query_context(data: T) -> QueryContext[T]:
    return QueryContext(data)


def get_user_context(user: User) -> QueryContext[User]:
    return get_query_context(user)


def get_item_context(item: Item) -> QueryContext[Item]:
    return get_query_context(item)


@app.post("/update_user")
async def update_user(user: User, ctx: QueryContext[User] = Depends(get_user_context)):
    ...


@app.post("/update_item")
async def update_item(item: Item, ctx: QueryContext[Item] = Depends(get_item_context)):
    ...


Thanks for your answer. However, your code does not work properly, 422 HTTP status code received, and the error is: {"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["query","params"],"msg":"Field required","input":null}]}.

Could you please provide query and body of request that receive 422?

Replace the original definition with the function signature you provided, then simply use the requests package to send a post request:
`import requests
resp = requests.post(
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_user",
json={"full_name": "john", "nickname": "jo", "age": 32},
)
print(resp.status_code, resp.content)`

I see.. I've edited my answer. Seems like you need separated Dependencies for different objects. Try this out please

It works! But it seems that i have to write a function to wrap the generic function get_query_context for every model? This isn't very pleasant, the pain of boilerplate code just takes a different form  : (

An alternative solution, not perfect
New status
After some exploration, I found a better way to reduce code duplication and solve this problem. Unfortunately, this still does not use the Depends provided by FastAPI, so it's not perfect.
In order not to interfere with the original meaning of the question, I provide the solution I explored in the form of an answer so that those who need it can refer to it.
Any other answer is still welcome! Many thanks.
Idea
FastAPI will only read the signature of the function modified by the path endpoint decorator (I am not sure if this term is correct, this refers to the decorator such as @route.post() or @app.get()) for validation, so we can do one more layer of packaging, modify its function signature before passing our business function to the path endpoint decorator. This let FastAPI read the modified signature to use Pydantic to automatically validate, and let the user programmer (that is, us) use the unmodified function signature of the type containing the context class for convenient development. To implement this, just define a decorator and call it before the path endpoint decorator.
Solution
# file: QueryContext.py
from copy import deepcopy
from functools import wraps
from inspect import Parameter, Signature, signature
from typing import Callable, Generic, TypeVar, get_args, get_origin
from uuid import uuid4

def use_query_ctx(func: Callable):
    need_wrap_ctx = set()
    sig_wrapped = signature(func)

    @wraps(wrapped=func) # still need this for update other meta info of wrapped function
    async def wrapper(**kwargs):
        ctx_dict = {
            kw: QueryContext(arg) if kw in need_wrap_ctx else arg
            for kw, arg in kwargs.items()
        }
        return_val = await func(**ctx_dict)
        return return_val

    sig_no_wrapped = Signature(
        [
            Parameter(
                name=param.name,
                kind=param.kind,
                default=param.default,
                annotation=(
                    get_args(param.annotation)[0]
                    if get_origin(param.annotation) is QueryContext
                    else param.annotation
                ),
            )
            for param in sig_wrapped.parameters.values()
        ]
    )
    need_wrap_ctx.update(
        {
            (
                param.name
                if get_origin(param.annotation) is QueryContext
                else param.annotation
            )
            for param in sig_wrapped.parameters.values()
        }
    )
    wrapper.__signature__ = sig_no_wrapped
    return wrapper

T = TypeVar("T")

class QueryContext(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, raw_params: T):
        self.request_UUID = uuid4()
        self._raw_params = raw_params
        self.curr_params = deepcopy(raw_params)
        self.extra: dict = {}
        self.pre_return: dict = {}
        return

    @property
    def raw_params(self):
        return self._raw_params

    @raw_params.setter
    def raw_params(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise AttributeError("Cannot modify raw params!")

Test
Server file:
# file: server.py
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Body, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

from QueryContext import QueryContext, use_query_ctx

app = FastAPI()


class User(BaseModel):
    full_name: str
    nickname: str
    age: int


class Detail(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: float
    alias: str = ""
    brand: str = ""
    detail: Detail | None = None


@app.post("/simple")
@use_query_ctx
async def update_user(ctx: QueryContext[User]):
    print(f"{ctx.raw_p=}")
    ctx.curr_p.full_name += " (elder version)"
    ctx.curr_p.age += 15
    print(
        f"request {ctx.uuid} done.\nraw params: {ctx.raw_p}\ncurr params: {ctx.curr_p}"
    )
    return ctx.curr_p


@app.post("/complex/{single_path}")
@use_query_ctx
async def update_user(
    single_path: int,
    query: float,
    ctx: QueryContext[User],
    ctx2: QueryContext[Item],
    single_body: Annotated[int, Body()],
    no_ctx_model: Item,
):
    print(f"{single_path=}")
    print(f"{query=}")
    print(f"{ctx.raw_p=}")
    print(f"{ctx2.raw_p=}")
    print(f"{single_body=}")
    print(f"{no_ctx_model=}")

    ctx.curr_p.full_name = "new full name"
    ctx.curr_p.age += 5
    print(
        f"request {ctx.uuid} done.\nraw params: {ctx.raw_p}\ncurr params: {ctx.curr_p}"
    )
    return ctx.curr_p

A test file:
# file: test.py
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # simple, will success
    resp = requests.post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/simple",
        json={"full_name": "john", "nickname": "jo", "age": 32},
    )
    print(resp.status_code, resp.content)

    # simple, will fail because required field `age` not provided
    resp = requests.post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/simple",
        json={"full_name": "john", "nickname": "jo"},
    )
    print(resp.status_code, resp.content)

    # complex example with path, query, nested pydantic models and single body param
    # will success
    resp = requests.post(
        f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/complex/514?query=15.234",
        json={
            "ctx": {"full_name": "john", "nickname": "jo", "age": 32},
            "ctx2": {
                "name": "john",
                "price": 32.99,
                "detail": {
                    "a": "it's a",
                    "b": "it's b",
                },
            },
            "single_body": 42,
            "no_ctx_model": {
                "name": "what!",
                "price": 1.99,
            },
        },
    )
    print(resp.status_code, resp.content)

Run result of server side:
# server side:
fastapi dev server.py
# ......
INFO:     Started server process [2709916]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
# Initialization done.

ctx.raw_p=User(full_name='john', nickname='jo', age=32)
request ac4d56b9-fa31-4021-a16f-b1dbc7184ff9 done.
raw params: full_name='john' nickname='jo' age=32
curr params: full_name='john (elder version)' nickname='jo' age=47
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59474 - "POST /simple HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59476 - "POST /simple HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
single_path=514
query=15.234
ctx.raw_p=User(full_name='john', nickname='jo', age=32)
ctx2.raw_p=Item(name='john', price=32.99, alias='', brand='', detail=Detail(a="it's a", b="it's b"))
single_body=42
no_ctx_model=Item(name='what!', price=1.99, alias='', brand='', detail=None)
request 679210a3-9db6-4924-b70c-20e0a3ba03e9 done.
raw params: full_name='john' nickname='jo' age=32
curr params: full_name='new full name' nickname='jo' age=37
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59478 - "POST /complex/514?query=15.234 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

Run result of client side:
200 b'{"full_name":"john (elder version)","nickname":"jo","age":47}'
422 b'{"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body","age"],"msg":"Field required","input":{"full_name":"john","nickname":"jo"}}]}'
200 b'{"full_name":"new full name","nickname":"jo","age":37}'

